# Incrementing a counter in nested foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to manually increment a ViewModel property from within a Knockout `foreach` binding?

I want to do something logically equivalent to:

```
var inc = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        inc++;
        alert(inc + ': ' + i + ',' + j); // but write this to the dom
    }
}
```

I have tried to use `$index`, but that just relates to the current loop, not the inner or parent loop.

The arrays may be different sizes, so I cannot simply calculate the `$parentContext.$index * [count of child items] + current $index`.

What I am trying to achieve:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: Categories">
    <div data-bind="foreach: SubCategories" >
       <div data-bind="text: [someIncrementer] +': ' + $parent.Category + ',' + $data></div>
       <!-- should output: 
       1: A,1
       2: A,2 
       3: A,3  
       4: B,1
       5: B,3
       -->
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var ViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Categories = ko.observableArray([
       {Category: 'A', SubCategories: [1,2,3]}, 
       {Category: 'B', SubCategories: [1,3]}
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to make this any more complicated than it has to be. You could try something like this:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  var index = 0;
  self.inc = function(val) {
    return ++index;
  }

  self.Categories = ko.observableArray([{
    Category: 'A',
    SubCategories: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    Category: 'B',
    SubCategories: [1, 3]
  }]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Categories">
  <!-- ko foreach: SubCategories -->
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: $root.inc() + ': ' + $parent.Category + ', ' + $data"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly (for my needs). I can create another method to get the current incrementer / just expose the internal incrementer on the object, `self.Incrementer = 0`

Comment: This will not work I think, not in real scenarios where there are observables in play. Every time the `text` binding is re-evaluated (e.g. whenever a category name would change, if it were observable), the `inc` function would be called again, without resetting the numbering back to 0.

Comment: Correct, you'd have to account for changes to your array.

Comment: Jeroen has illustrated a good point. If youre not planning on modifying data in your array then feel free to stick with the above, but in most real world scenarios you'll be making modifications to your array and, well, you've seen his fiddle above...

Answer (score 2):

Create a computed observable with the flattened array for that:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.Categories = ko.observableArray([
    {Category: 'A', SubCategories: [1,2,3]}, 
    {Category: 'B', SubCategories: [1,3]}
  ]);

  self.FlattenedSubcategories = ko.computed(function() {
    var result = [], cats = self.Categories(), index = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < cats[i].SubCategories.length; j++) {
        result.push({
          Idx: index++,
          Category: cats[i].Category,
          Subcat: cats[i].SubCategories[j]
        });
      }
    }
    return result;
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: FlattenedSubcategories">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: Idx"></span>:
    <span data-bind="text: Category"></span>,
    <span data-bind="text: Subcat"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, too. Sometimes it's useful to nest `foreach` to be able to create a certain HTML structure, in this example it does not make a difference though.

Comment: Jeroen, this approach may work. My actual model is much more complex (tried to dumb it down for an easy StackOverflow example). I am generating a more complex HTML structure so an ordered list won't work. A calculated flattened array could work, but I would have to then do a lookup against it. I think I might need to calculate the "index" server side as one of the data elements. Thanks though, this was helpful!

Comment: I figured that you'd have more complex (sub)category objects. My solution will only hold up to a certain extent for sure, depending on the *actual* data and view models. - I'm not sure though what you mean by "*have to do a lookup against it*", but you might need to ask a seperate question with a repro on that topic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<ol>` / `<li>` with a numerical counter or a [CSS counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

This works if the number is purely for display purposes and nothing depends on it.

```js
var ViewModel = function()
{
    var self = this;
    self.Categories = ko.observableArray([
       {Category: 'A', SubCategories: [1,2,3]}, 
       {Category: 'B', SubCategories: [1,3]},
       {Category: 'C', SubCategories: [7,8,9]},
       {Category: 'D', SubCategories: [10,11,12,13]}
    ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
.categories {
  counter-reset: category;
}
.subcategory::before {
  counter-increment: category;
  content: counter(category) ": ";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="categories" data-bind="foreach: Categories">
    <div data-bind="foreach: SubCategories">
        <div>
          <span class="subcategory" data-bind="text: $parent.Category + ',' + $data"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

Like you said, the knockout binding context exposes an `$index` observable that holds the index in the loop. There's also the `$parentContext` to refer to the context that's higher up in the chain.

For a simple, 2 level nested loop, you could create a helper method that uses the current `$index` and the parent's `$index` to calculate the total index:

```
// cIndex = current category's index
// sIndex = current subcategory's index
self.getSubIndex = function(cIndex, sIndex) {
  return sIndex + self.Categories
    .slice(0, cIndex)
    .reduce(function(count, c) {
      return count + c.SubCategories.length;
    }, 0);
}
```

It'll be a bit annoying to write though:

```
<span data-bind="text: $root.getSubIndex($parentContext.$index(), $index())">   </span>
```

You could also pass `$context` and get the indexes inside the `getSubIndex` method. You could even go through the context chain recursively until there's no more `$index` property to be found.

Personally, I'd rather create an `index` computed in the `SubCategory` viewmodels, which would feel a bit less hacky. However, it would require the `SubCategory` to have access to its parent...

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
 

  self.Categories = ko.observableArray([{
    Category: 'A',
    SubCategories: [1, 2, 3]
  }, {
    Category: 'B',
    SubCategories: [1, 3]
  }]);
  
  self.getSubIndex = function(cIndex, sIndex) {
    return sIndex + self.Categories
      .slice(0, cIndex)
      .reduce(function(count, c) {
        return count + c.SubCategories.length;
      }, 0);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: Categories">
  <!-- ko foreach: SubCategories -->
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: $root.getSubIndex($parentContext.$index(), $index()) + ': ' + $parent.Category + ', ' + $data"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```